# What is this .LWT extention

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, file-extension

I found a old verbatim usb with nothing on it, however after using recuva on it I was able to pull off a variety of old files, going through the list I found a strange file called _HOTOS.LWT . The only thing I could find linked to the file is a program called lightwright which I know my family and I have never used. Only other thing on the flash drive was v-safe 100. So I don't know if that is the name that program gives it's encrypted volumes but I don't believe so.

**My question is what is the .LWT extention for**

Other details

- Flash drive only used on windows 10 and windows xp to my knowledge
- Flash drive had v-safe 100.exe on it
- The only other files I could detect on the drive were photos

Thanks for your help?

Comment: *Did you  check the internet?* http://filext.com/file-extension/LWT suggests Dymo taperwriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out after digging into the file I found this street address 7835 MacArthur, Irving TX 75063. And the name Eckerd. Upon further digging I found this store used to be there.
https://www.yelp.com/biz/eckerd-drugs-irving-4 a store that would develope photos. From what I can guess this was a file maybe that came on a photo cd after they had processed some photos we had taken in, as the .lwt file also contained image0001.jpg all the way to image0012.jpg in it's text. I still wonder what the rest of the stuff in the file means but thats for another day.

Well this was a interesting adventure.